# Search on all opened workbooks for specific data and select that one workbook to use his data

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub SearchOnWorksheets()
    Dim sPrompt As String
    Dim msgTrap As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim xWBName As String
    Dim xWBAbiertos As String
    Dim wSheet As Worksheet
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim bFound As Boolean


    If Workbooks.Count >= 2 Then
        For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
           xWBAbiertos = xWBAbiertos & "[ " & wBook.Name & " ]" & vbCrLf
        Next
        For Each wBook In Application.Workbooks
            For Each wSheet In wBook.Worksheets
                Set rFound = Nothing
                Set rFound = wSheet.Cells.Find(What:="raya", After:=wSheet.Cells(1, 1), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    bFound = True
                    xWBName = wBook.Name & vbCrLf
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next wSheet
            If bFound = True Then Exit For
        Next wBook
        sPrompt = "Archivos Excel abiertos:" & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & xWBAbiertos & vbNewLine & _
            vbNewLine & "El archivo de donde se extraerán los gastos es:" & vbNewLine & _
            vbNewLine & xWBName & vbNewLine & _
            vbNewLine & ""

        msgTrap = MsgBox(sPrompt, vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "CUBIMSA")

        Select Case msgTrap
            Case vbYes
                Exit Sub
            Case vbNo
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    Else
        Call MsgBox("THERE IS NO OPENED ARCHIVE." & vbNewLine & _
        vbNewLine & "OPEN ARCHIVE", vbCritical, "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

[image]

In this message appears the file "gastos.xls" because the code looks for the word "raya" in every opened workbook, but I need it to show all the workbooks that met this criteria.
Or maybe if it is possible in all the workbooks look for the sheet "Raya Semanal".

And I need to use this workbook to extract some information, how can I convert this string on something I can copy and paste in other workbook?
something like `Workbooks("gastos.xls").Sheets("Raya Semanal").Range("Z16").Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking for 2 things:

> I need it to show all the workbooks that met this criteria

In order to record all foundings for all the WBs you would need to change this line `xWBName = wBook.Name & vbCrLf` to `xWBName = wBook.Name & vbCrLf & xWBName`

> And I need to use this workbook to extract some information, how can I convert this string on something I can copy and paste in other workbook?

I would use the split Function

Like so:

```
  Dim ItemArray as Variant 
  For Each ItemArray in Split(xWBName ,vbCrlf) 'I may be wrong and probably you should use Chr(10) instead of vbcrlf
  Workbooks(Cstr(ItemArray)).Sheets("Raya Semanal").Range("Z16").Value
  Next ItemArray
```

Comment: this worked   Dim ItemArray as Variant 
  For Each ItemArray in Split(xWBName ,vbCrlf)
  Workbooks(Cstr(ItemArray)).Sheets("Raya Semanal").Range("Z16").Value
  Next ItemArray
this dindn't show any other result xWBName = wBook.Name & vbCrLf & xWBName

Comment: You'd need to save that value in a variable, you're just looping through the wb in the array

Comment: @CarlosHernándezQuiñones You break your loop with `If bFound = True Then Exit For`. Delete this line and you'll be fine.